# Query the dimensions of a model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a way to get the dimensions of an object in (Ignition) Gazebo? I guess it's solvable by implementing a custom plugin, but are there any simpler ways? Maybe a service i'm missing?

Update:
To clarify, i want to know is the width/height/depth of a model's bounding box downloaded from fuel. I think this is what the ModelPhotoShoot plugin does internally: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/3bde4b5318f9bed37e2fc8dbe5877bbdc9b73ae1/src/systems/model_photo_shoot/ModelPhotoShoot.cc#L235

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29113/query-the-dimensions-of-a-model/) by [azazdeaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34541/azazdeaz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2023-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2023-05-30**:
Can you explain a little more what you want? An "object" is too vague because it's not clear if you want the dimension of the whole model, just a link, or a single visual/collision in the link.

**Comment by [azazdeaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34541/azazdeaz/) on 2023-05-31**:
Thanks! I updated the question. I was thinking the size of a model, but if there is a solution for querying the bounding box of a link, or a part of a link, i'm also very interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo has a [bounding box camera sensor](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.9&elem=sensor#sensor_type). I can't find a tutorial that covers how to use it, but there's an [example](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/3bde4b5318f9bed37e2fc8dbe5877bbdc9b73ae1/examples/worlds/boundingbox_camera.sdf#L379) in gz-sim that you can look at. The camera publishes a vector of `AnnotatedOriented[2,3]DBox` types, which you can learn about [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-msgs/blob/gz-msgs9/proto/gz/msgs/annotated_oriented_3d_box.proto)

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2023-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1